# How to assign an array a different index value in C++

Tags: c++

So I have been able to perform this action in C# and Java, but am unable to do it in C++. Below is the code, it is short and simple, I am simply searching to see how to perform an action like this using c++. **Update** It seems that this is not possible in C++ as you must use a vector instead. If I am not mistaken, a vector and array are two different things therefore the puzzle I am solving will only work with Java, C#, and I am yet to try PHP, or JS.

```
    //Java
    double[] x = new double[15];
   //C++ Not Working :(
   double x[3];
   x = new double[15];
```

Comment: You can't do that, you would need to use a pointer, or preferably, a vector which is a resizable array.

Comment: What does your C++ textbook have to say on the subject? C++ is really nothing like Java or C#.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I totally agree! I have this weird tick where if I learn a new puzzle, I have to write that puzzle in every programming language I am familiar with, this helps me remember the algorithm and brush up on C++, as I use C# a lot more than C++ these days.

Comment: @Russell That will teach you more about the differences between languages than the puzzle in question. This may be worthwhile, but you need to approach it with a different mindset; your question shouldn't be "how do I do this thing in C++?" but "what is this thing on an abstract level and how does C++ represent this thing?". The intermediate step is important, because only this way do you truly learn something about the language. (In this particular case, you would learn that C++ arrays have their size as part of the type, which neither answer told you.)

Comment: @SebastianRedl reading this years later makes me smile! Now that I have been in the Biz for a few years, I can say you are 100% right!

Answer (score 3):

C-style arrays are no fun to use  at all. A C++ dynamic array is an `std::vector`, which is used as follows:

```
std::vector<double> x(3);    // A dynamic array of 3 `double`s
x.resize(15);                // Keep the three values at the beginning, or...
x = std::vector<double>(15); // ... discard them.
```

Comment: @Russell that deadpan joke was much funnier when I wrote it. Good luck with PHP ;)

Comment: Thank you for all of your help. I get a little sensitive on here as I feel like I get picked on a lot. But I can see you were joking and can 100% appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

a variable length array in c++ is modelled by the template class `std::vector`:

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    auto x = std::vector<double>(3);

    // now working
    x = std::vector<double>(15);

    // or
    x.resize(15);
}
```